# Calculate number of table rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, numbers, rows

I have a mysql table with up to 2.000.000 Records

How can in the fastest time calculate the number of rows in the table?

Comment: select count(*) from table_name;

Comment: Do you need an exact answer?

Comment: You can select from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES` table using `TABLE_ROWS` see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exact count for all storage engines:

```
select count(*) from table1;
```

For faster MyISAM exact count or InnoDB estimated count:

```
show table status;
```

or

```
select table_schema, table_name, table_rows from information_schema where table_name = 'table1' and table_schema = 'schema1';
```

see [MySQL show status documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-table-status.html)

see [MySQL infromation_schema.tables documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This fastet

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `sometable` WHERE somefield = 'somecondition'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;` is the fastest way to calculate the numbers of rows because it uses column indexes. if you're using MyISAM engine then it actually stores row count and it doesn't count rows each time you issue `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` 
Further Clarification is here

[COUNT(*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)